# Como manter áudio de uma cena pra outra no Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity-5, áudio

Preciso de ajuda.

Estou fazendo um jogo 2D no Unity. E gostaria de saber como faço pra manter o áudio (música de fundo) de uma cena pra outra e que ele continuasse de onde parou. E também como eu faria pra especificar as cenas que ele deve continuar, e as cenas que ele deve ser destruído.

Answer (score 3):

Para reproduzir o áudio da sua música de fundo presumo que você tenha um *game object* na cena com um componente *AudioSource* anexado. Para manter este objeto existindo ao longo de outras cenas e mantê-lo reproduzindo a mesma música, você poder utilizar um *script* que o impeça de ser destruído durante o carregamento de cenas. Seria algo assim:

```c#
class DontDestroyThis : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start()
    {   
        // Este método impede que o objeto 
        // atual seja destruido durante o carregamento.
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Simples assim, crie um script C# com o nome *DontDestroyThis* e utilize esta implementação no método *Start*. Anexe este script ao objeto que contém o *AudioSource*. Pronto, sua música de fundo continuará tocando ao longo das cenas.

Para definir quais cenas vc quer que ele continue tocando ou não, você poderia ter um outro *script* em cada uma das cenas que faria esse gerenciamento para você. Então você poderia usar os métodos *Play, Stop, UnPause* e *Pause* para controlar a reprodução do áudio. Exemplo:

```c#
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
class AudioManagerExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        // Obtém o objeto da cena que possui o AudioClip
        // é bom manter uma convenção para o nome deste objeto.
        // Neste exemplo BGM.
        GameObject audioSourceGameObject = GameObject.Find("BGM");

        // Obtém o componente AudioSource do objeto.
        AudioSource source = audioSourceGameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        // Utilize as linhas abaixo conforme necessário
        // para controlar a reprodução.
        source.Play();      // Inicia a reprodução do áudio.
        source.Stop();      // Pára a reprodução do áudio, inicia do começo quando for reproduzido novamente.
        source.UnPause();   // Despausa a reprodução previamente pausada. Similar ao Play após um audio ter sido pausado.
        source.Pause();     // Pausa a reprodução.

        // Exemplo:
        if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "NomeDaCenaDesejada")
        {
            source.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            source.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Para mais informações, você pode consultar a documentação da *API* de *script* do componente *AudioSource* diretamente no site da *Unity*:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html